# Error on BPMN Process thrown when executing JUnit Test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, camunda

this is as wierd as I'm about to explain. I'm working on a project with a collegue and we were trying to do some JUnit tests when the following happened.

```
2019-07-23 12:36:29.030  WARN 10068 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.util              : ENGINE-09004 Warnings during parsing: 
* schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'BPMNDI.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 8 | column 96
* schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'Semantic.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 9 | column 46
2019-07-23 12:36:29.036 ERROR 10068 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.context           : ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'extension' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 15 | column 70
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'rootElement' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 16 | column 72
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'bpmndi:BPMNDiagram' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 17 | column 79
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'relationship' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 18 | column 73
* cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":process}'. One of '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":import}' is expected. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 11 | column 126

org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'extension' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 15 | column 70
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'rootElement' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 16 | column 72
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'bpmndi:BPMNDiagram' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 17 | column 79
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'relationship' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 18 | column 73
* cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":process}'. One of '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":import}' is expected. | bpmn/hello.bpmn | line 11 | column 126
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.exceptionDuringParsing(EngineUtilLogger.java:61)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:207)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:271)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.transformDefinitions(BpmnDeployer.java:104)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.transformResource(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:98)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.parseDefinitionResources(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:73)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.deploy(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:63)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:53)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:50)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:477)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer.deploy(CacheDeployer.java:50)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:66)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:64)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.deploy(DeployCmd.java:485)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:141)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:129)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:477)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.doExecute(DeployCmd.java:129)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:95)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:75)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:27)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.deployWithResult(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:101)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deployWithResult(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:269)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:265)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.ProcessApplicationDeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(ProcessApplicationDeploymentBuilderImpl.java:62)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.deployment.DeployProcessArchiveStep.performOperationStep(DeployProcessArchiveStep.java:144)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:119)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.executeDeploymentOperation(MBeanServiceContainer.java:159)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation$DeploymentOperationBuilder.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:215)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.deployProcessApplication(RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.java:101)
    at org.camunda.bpm.application.AbstractProcessApplication.deploy(AbstractProcessApplication.java:62)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.start(SpringProcessApplication.java:109)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.afterPropertiesSet(SpringProcessApplication.java:118)
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.SpringBootProcessApplication.afterPropertiesSet(SpringBootProcessApplication.java:90)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:95)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringProcessApplication.onApplicationEvent(SpringProcessApplication.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:896)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

and the list keeps going

The bpmn it is making conflict goes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:tns="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="Definitions_1d1wun5" name="" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="2.2.4">
  <bpmn:process id="hello" name="hello" processType="None" isClosed="true" isExecutable="true" camunda:historyTimeToLive="1">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="hello_startEvent" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1l75f9h" sourceRef="hello_startEvent" targetRef="Hello_service_task" />
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Hello_service_task" name="hello" camunda:delegateExpression="#{helloservice}" activiti:exclusive="true" />
    <bpmn:endEvent id="Hello_endEvent" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0y8xoxl" sourceRef="Hello_service_task" targetRef="Hello_endEvent" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="Diagram-_1" name="New Diagram" documentation="background=#3C3F41;count=1;horizontalcount=1;orientation=0;width=842.4;height=1195.2;imageableWidth=832.4;imageableHeight=1185.2;imageableX=5.0;imageableY=5.0">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="hello">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Shape-hello_startEvent" bpmnElement="hello_startEvent">
        <dc:Bounds x="173" y="102" width="32" height="32" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Shape-Hello_service_task" bpmnElement="Hello_service_task">
        <dc:Bounds x="296" y="80" width="100" height="80" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="0" y="0" width="100" height="80" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Shape-Hello_endEvent" bpmnElement="Hello_endEvent">
        <dc:Bounds x="512" y="102" width="32" height="32" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_0y8xoxl" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0y8xoxl" sourceElement="Hello_service_task" targetElement="Hello_endEvent">
        <di:waypoint x="396" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint x="512" y="118" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="-1" y="-1" width="-1" height="-1" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_1l75f9h" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1l75f9h" sourceElement="hello_startEvent" targetElement="Hello_service_task">
        <di:waypoint x="205" y="118" />
        <di:waypoint x="296" y="120" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="-1" y="-1" width="-1" height="-1" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

i've tried to delete the bpmn to see what happens and it just gives error on another BPMN

The wierdest of it all is that it works perfectly fine on my collegue computer.
I've tried importing his configurations, I've tried reseting my intellij and nothing seems to work.

Thank you to anyone willing to help